# How to prevent wordpress from loading old versions of jquery in wp_head();?

Tags: jquery, javascript, headers, include, scripts

I noticed my twenty twelve theme is including outdated versions of jquery and js so I want to replace the scripts with the newer versions, however the scripts are in the file included by wp_head() (which I think is in wp-includes) so adding the scripts to my header means jquery will be loaded twice, I see now way to remove the scripts from wp_head() without messing with wp-include and any changes I do will probably be lost if I update wordpress.

So how can I remove the scripts from wp_head() permanently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_more_jquery');
function no_more_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```

That will deregister jquery. But why wouldn't you want jQuery at all?

If you mean to simply use your own, you should do it in that function, like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_more_jquery');
function no_more_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . 
    ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . 
    "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

This example loads Google's jquery, but you could easily load one that you have in your own theme folder. You can read more about this process here: [Function Reference/wp enqueue script « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

P.S. That would go in functions. And it is not a great idea to just stuff jquery library calls in your header, as it conflicts with plugins or other things that might be looking for jQuery to be present.

Comment: thanks. I added jquery and jquery-ui through this way. I don't want to change anything outside my child theme so this is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to update jQuery is to use [jQuery Updater plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-updater/)

If you just want to remove the wordpress version then add

`wp_deregister_script('jquery');`

to your `functions.php`